# How do I get this CSS to work in safari

Tags: css, safari

I am currently testing some CSS in different web browsers. This all works great except in Safari 5.1.7. I am testing this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/8/) . Does anyone know how I can fix this, because I would like to use it in a website.

The css is supposed to display a heading with a colored line either side.

Here is the code:

[HTML]

```
<h1>This is my Title</h1>
<h1>Another Similar Title</h1>
<div class="color"><h1>Just Title</h1></div>
```

[CSS]

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.color {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: which part of css is not working??

Comment: I don't know. It is just not displaying the red line on the left side of the heading. But it works in every other browser I have tested Opera, Chrome, IE and Firefox

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about Safari for windows. It's a dead browser as it hasn't been updated for years. The percentage for users has to be lower than 1%

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 is 6 years old with near-zero usage (http://caniuse.com/usage-table) - given the number of users that will see it, will a graceful fallback be sufficient? It works great in modern Safari.

Comment: So how do I test that this works on Safari on Mac. I have a pc

Comment: you'll have to test with a mac or iphone, ipad.

Comment: Can someone with a Mac confirm this works?

Comment: safari 5.1.7 doesn't support `:before` `:after` pseudo classes http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: Oh. drat. Is there an alternative syntax I can use?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Safari 5.1.7 support `:before` and `:after`. Safari 9.* series is for Mac Platform. Try some code with `:after` or `:before` pseudo class and it will work in `5.1.7` version in Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use one element inside `h1` and use `:before` and `:after` with `left` and `right` properties. This will work in most of the browsers including Safari.

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
h1 span:before, h1 span:after {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 9999px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '\a0';
  left: 100%;
}
h1 span:before {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
.color {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is my Title</span></h1>
<h1><span>Another Similar Title</span></h1>
<div class="color">
  <h1><span>Just Title</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain the difference??

Comment: @GauravAggarwal I've added a little bit explanation which will definitely solve the problem but I've not plans to explain the different behavior of `:after` and `:before` in each browser.